# Function forwarding argument and simply doing nothing

Tags: c++, c++14, perfect-forwarding

For a template default case, I need a function that does nothing but simply forwards whatever it receives as an argument. Specifically, references, const-ness etc. should be preserved. Writing `transparent(/* something */)` should be completely equivalent to writing `/* something */`.

Is the following function definition correct for achieving that purpose?

```
template <class S>
decltype(auto) transparent (S && s) { return std::forward<S> (s); }
```

Comment: I think that implementation is correct. But what's the purpose? You basically renamed `std::forward`.

Comment: `template <class DistinguishCases> struct Transform { /* operator ()  should do nothing */ }; template <> struct Transform <SpecialCase> { MyOtherType operator () (MyType t) { return wrap(t); };`. I want to use it in a template function like `return Transform<Case> {} ( /* whatever my function calculates */ );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `constexpr` and it's as good as it gets. prvalues will yield xvalues; However, that's not improvable since one cannot distinguish prvalues and xvalues using overload resolution.

You won't be able to properly forward `0` as a null pointer constant or string literals as initializers, but the only way to achieve that would be a macro (which is not what you're going for).

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is fine, but here are some things  to come to mind:

> If a call to transparent () passes an rvalue std::string, then is
>   deduced to std::string, and std::forward ensures that an rvalue
>   reference is return.
>
> If a call to transparent () passes a const lvalue std::string, then S
>   is deduced to const std::string&, and std::forward ensures that a
>   const lvalue reference will return
>
> If a call to transparent () passes a non-const lvalue std::string,
>   then S is deduced to std::string&, and std::forward ensures that a
>   non-const lvalue reference will return

But why do you need this? A common use to 
std::forward in templates is to the a warpper like that:

```
template<class T>
void wrapper(T&& arg) 
{
    foo(std::forward<T>(arg)); // Forward a single argument.
}
```

Comment: I need a metafunction that does a forward if its parameter (the parameter of the metafunction) is one type and does something else if its parameter is another type. The parameter to the metafunction is unrelated to the type of the expression I'm forwarding.